# if we create a database using mysql,where the database will be created in the pc

Tags: mysql, database, terminal, visibility, except

when we create a database using mysql we can retrieve those databases only by typing 'show details" in the terminal.Is there a way other than that to access the database like, just by opening a folder in a drive?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/ Try this link. He explains where to find it on both windows and linux. The question is why do you want access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Every database has a folder on the drive, usually they will be saved in the "data" folder in "mysql" folder on windows try:

```
c:\program files\mysql\data
```

and you can get it by:

```
mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'
```

Locate the file **my.cnf** on linux, and **my.ini** on windows 
it should tell you where the data directory is.

eg.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

I hope that helped you ...

Answer (score 0):

First locate your `my.ini` file stored in your myssql installation directory.
Open the file with a text editor of your choice and then look for `datadir` in the file.

This is what it looks like:

```
datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a database using option like create new database you can set path for both row data and log file

for row data

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

for log file

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

or you can check database properties.Right click database and click properties, a new window will be open again click files.Here you can see where was the database stored